# Split a text in blocks of text when encountering a defalult sign

Tags: c#

So, I have been working with some texts.

I've trying to separate the text in multiple blocks when I encountered '$'sign in text. In my example I used two `richTextBox`. I tried using **lists**, and `Split()` method but it didn't work so well.

```
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(@"texte\Senzatii\definirea&caracterizarea_senzatiilor.txt");
        string lines = "";

        int state = 1;
        while ((lines = read.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (lines == "$".ToString())
                state = 2;

            if (state == 1)
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + lines + "\n";
            else
                richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox2.Text + lines + "\n";
        }
```

This method works, it splits the text into two block of texts, but it doesn't look so good. Is there a better way to split the text into two blocks of text, a more *c# way, solution* to do this ?

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a sample file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using lists, and Split() method but it didn't work so well.

Hard to help with almost no informations. But if you want to split on this `$` sign. What's wrong with:

```
string[] bothParts = File.ReadAllText(@"texte\Senzatii\definirea&caracterizarea_senzatiilor.txt")
    .Split('$');
string firstPart = bothParts[0];
string secondPart = bothParts.ElementAtOrDefault(1);

richTextBox1.Text = firstPart;
richTextBox2.Text = secondPart;
```